# TFS 2013 - Configuration parameter approach using build and release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, msdeploy

I'm a bit confused about whats the recomended way of configuring build and release in TFS2017 on prem. Currently (tfs2013) we have different publish profiles for TEST and PROD and using WebDeploy.

This is what I whant to achive:

- Use the "environment variables and relase definition variables" in TFS instead of storing them in web.config.TEST-01 etc
- Grab the latest build and modify web.config (connectionstrings, appsettings) and deploy this build to our TEST machines
- Some time later, send the same build that was used above to PROD (modify web.config)

What is the recommended approach when we now should move to TFS2017? Is web transform still the best option? I found this article [modify web.config](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps) describing a Set-AzureWebsite and a Tokenization approach. Will it work on-prem also?

And does it matter how we deploy to our local IIS? I found this taks [IIS Webapp deploy using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) - but in case WebDeploy, we probably need the webdeploy prarameterfile? Or not? Are there better tasks for deploy?

Thanks for any help

Lars

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using XAML build to build and deploy your project in TFS 2013. The new build system in TFS 2015 and later is totally different from XAML build. The new task system is based on JSON descriptor files with activities written as PowerShell (for Windows) or Node JS (for cross-platform), which is more flexible.

From Team Foundation Server 2015 (update 2 and above), Web Access also integrate **Release** tab, you can add a series of tasks (like IIS Webapp deploy using WinRM) to deploy your project.

We suggest use new tasks based build/release system, and add tasks or scripts to build/release/deploy your project.

Useful links:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/overview
- https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/release/managing-releases/create-release
- https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/release/getting-started/release-notes#whatsnew

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But the question is really about configuration handling. And to me it's still unclear what approach to choose to get the custom variables in the release environments (like connection strings) into the web.config files.

Comment: @Larsi, when you use new build/release system, you can install Replace Tokens extension from website https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens, then you will be able to add Replace Tokens task in your build/release definition to replace tokens in files with variable values.